# Filtering collection of key/value pairs. How can I access the key?

Tags: php, laravel

I am filtering through a collection of key/value pairs. While I am filtering, how can I access the key?

Keys are:

- title
- body
- active
- button
- button-2

How can I return fields whose key starts with "button"?

In this case, I would only like to get the button and button-2 field.

[image]

```
$fields = (stuff in picture)

// Pseudocode of what I'm trying to do
$button_fields = collect($fields)->filter(function($field){
    // I imagine getting the key should be something like this?             
    if($field->key->beginsWith('button')) {
         return;
    }
});
```

Comment: so you are basically asking how to check if a string starts with a particular string?  also does `$fields` hold all those fields under 'fields' or does it only have an element named 'fields'?

Comment: > so you are basically asking how to check if a string starts with a particular string? 

yes

> $fields holds all the fields under 'fields'

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I'm using php 7. Originally I did this with PHP as you can see in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/o5fda4rL/

Now i'm trying to figure out how to do this the laravel way.

Comment: Laravel has a `Str` helper class in `Illuminate\Support` that has a `startsWith` method  ... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-starts-with

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/earf48L6/

When I tried using the key, it said that the key was an object.

"Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"

Comment: well that data you are showing isn't from PHP so its hard to tell what you actually have

Comment: @alphabet You should take a look at the order of the arguments to the callable. [collection filter](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter) it's `($value, $key)`. Your fiddle shows the opposite

Answer (score 1):

On most collection methods the second parameter is the `$key`. This can be done, because you loop over an associative array, therefor the key is not indexed but a value. Secondly strings in `PHP` does not have methods, there for you should use the `Str` helper from `Laravel`, which takes two parameters the haystack first and the needle secondly.

```
$buttonFields = collect($fields)->filter(function($field, $key){            
    if(Str::startsWith($key, 'button')) {
         return;
    }
});
```